# Keyboard event fire with JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to copy to clipboard text from text box. And I do not want to use Flash. 
So I am trying to do with jQuery.

First I fire focus event on text box and then select event. And then I fired the ctrl+c key event, but it is not working.

My code:

```
<input type="button" onclick="copyText();" value="copy"></input>
<input type="text" value="abc" id="texttt"></input>


function copyText() {
    $("#texttt").focus();
    $("#texttt").select();

    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.ctrlKey = true; // ctrl key pressed
    e.which = 67; // # c code value

    $("#texttt").trigger(e);

}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#texttt").keydown(function (e) {

        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

        if (code == 67) {
            if (e.ctrlKey) {
                alert("ctrl+c was pressed!!");
                var e = jQuery.Event("keyup");

                e.which = 67;
                e.ctrlKey = true;

                $("#texttt").trigger(e);
            }
        }
    });

})
```

And here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/aps123/n5X5u/2/) to jsfiddle.

Comment: You cannot copy text to clipboard without flash. It's too much of an security issue. Browsers don't allow it!

Comment: IE does it (not the way you've done it), but none of the others will let you at all.

Comment: but why its not firing ctrl+c event with jquery